# A function contains tf.Session().run() gets slower and slower

Tags: python, tensorflow

I wrote a function to process some image with tensorflow, and the code looks like this:

```
def function:
    sess=tf.interactiveSession()
    for im in some_image_array
        new_list.append(sess.run(tf.cast(im,tf.float32)))
    sess.close()
```

I found that the using time of this function became longer with the repeated using, why and how can I improve it?

Comment: You are creating new `tf.cast` operations in the graph on each loop iteration. And if `some_image_array` contains actual arrays, and not TensorFlow tensors, you will be adding new (probably heavy) constants to the graph too. You should all the graph operations only once. If you want to use different inputs, use placeholders.

Comment: @jdehesa you're right. The images in `some_image_list` are actual array, but if I need to use some function of `tf.image` within the `for` loop ,how can i prevent the redundancy of `tf.cast`?

Comment: You should use a [`tf.placeholder`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder), apply the [`tf.cast`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cast) to it once, and the retrieve the result for each `im` passing a `feed_dict` to [`tf.Session.run`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#run).